# Load testing services to load CDN

Tags: cdn, load-testing

Any service can be used to load test a website on CDN? So that we can ensure our website still can run without problem even under high volume traffic for example DDoS.

I suppose the target service should able to generate huge amount concurrent connections and large bandwidth.

If there are any reference site or report, please guide me to.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://loadimpact.com/ and https://www.blitz.io/

Or you can always use tools like `siege` and `ab`